# How to pass method in python as a argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am new to Python and pytest, I am working on the page object model of python-selenium.

I want to pass the method as an argument but getting error. Here's my code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from PyFrame.pages.CheckoutPage import CheckoutPage


class ProductsPage:

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

    filter_dd = (By.CLASS_NAME, "product_sort_container")
    #sel_prod = (By.LINK_TEXT, "Price (low to high)")
    prod1 = (By.LINK_TEXT, "Sauce Labs Onesie")
    cart = (By.ID, "add-to-cart-sauce-labs-onesie")
    cart_logo= (By.CLASS_NAME , "shopping_cart_link")
    
    def selectprod(self, psel):
        pe = ProductsPage(self.driver)
        dropdown = Select(self.driver.find_element(*ProductsPage.filter_dd))
        dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Price (low to high)")
        self.driver.find_element(pe.sel_prd(psel)).click()
        self.driver.find_element(*ProductsPage.cart).click()
        self.driver.find_element(*ProductsPage.cart_logo).click()
        checkoutPage = CheckoutPage(self.driver)
        #prDpg = ProductsPage(self.driver)
        return checkoutPage
    
    def sel_prd(self,psel):
        self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, psel)
```

I want to pass "sel_prd" in

```
self.driver.find_element(pe.sel_prd(psel)).click()
```

In another class, I am passing string value

```
prdPage = ProductsPage(self.driver) 
prdPage.selectprod("Sauce Labs Onesie")
```

getting

```
    Tests/test_e2e.py::TestP::testone FAILED                                 [100%]
    Tests\test_e2e.py:12 (TestP.testone)
    self = <PyFrame.Tests.test_e2e.TestP object at 0x0000021A54822410>
    
        def testone(self):
            prdPage = ProductsPage(self.driver)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name").send_keys(
                "standard_user")  # driver is class variable now , therefore using it with self
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("secret_sauce", Keys.RETURN)
            time.sleep(3)
    >       checkoutpage = prdPage.selectprod("Sauce Labs Onesie")
    
    Tests\test_e2e.py:19: 
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    pages\ProductsPage.py:22: in selectprod
        self.driver.find_element(ProductsPage(self.driver).sel_prd(psel)).click()
    C:\Users\aman_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:1244: in find_element
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    C:\Users\aman_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:424: in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    
    self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x0000021A5486A3B0>
    response = {'status': 400, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"invalid argument","message":"invalid argument: \'using\' must be a string...dInitThunk [0x752D7D49+25]\\n\\tRtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x76F3B74B+107]\\n\\tRtlClearBits [0x76F3B6CF+191]\\n"}}'}
    
        def check_response(self, response: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
            """
            Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.
        
            :Args:
             - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
               object.
        
            :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
            """
            status = response.get('status', None)
            if not status or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
                return
            value = None
            message = response.get("message", "")
            screen: str = response.get("screen", "")
            stacktrace = None
            if isinstance(status, int):
                value_json = response.get('value', None)
                if value_json and isinstance(value_json, str):
                    import json
                    try:
                        value = json.loads(value_json)
                        if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                            value = value['value']
                        status = value.get('error', None)
                        if not status:
                            status = value.get("status", ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR)
                            message = value.get("value") or value.get("message")
                            if not isinstance(message, str):
                                value = message
                                message = message.get('message')
                        else:
                            message = value.get('message', None)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
        
           
        
            screen = None  # type: ignore[assignment]
            if 'screen' in value:
                screen = value['screen']
        
            stacktrace = None
            st_value = value.get('stackTrace') or value.get('stacktrace')
            if st_value:
                if isinstance(st_value, str):
                    stacktrace = st_value.split('\n')
                else:
                    stacktrace = []
                    try:
                        for frame in st_value:
                            line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                            file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                            if line:
                                file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                            meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                            if 'className' in frame:
                                meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                            msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                            msg = msg % (meth, file)
                            stacktrace.append(msg)
                    except TypeError:
                        pass
            if exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
                alert_text = None
                if 'data' in value:
                    alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
                elif 'alert' in value:
                    alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
                raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
    >       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    E       selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
    E         (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.138)
    E       Stacktrace:
    E       Backtrace:
    E           GetHandleVerifier [0x00DCDCE3+50899]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00D5E111]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00C65588]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00C909EC]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00C90AFB]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00CBF902]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00CAB944]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00CBE01C]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00CAB6F6]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00C87708]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00C8886D]
    E           GetHandleVerifier [0x01033EAE+2566302]
    E           GetHandleVerifier [0x010692B1+2784417]
    E           GetHandleVerifier [0x0106327C+2759788]
    E           GetHandleVerifier [0x00E65740+672048]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00D68872]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00D641C8]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00D642AB]
    E           (No symbol) [0x00D571B7]
    E           BaseThreadInitThunk [0x752D7D49+25]
    E           RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x76F3B74B+107]
    E           RtlClearBits [0x76F3B6CF+191]
    
    C:\Users\aman_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:247: InvalidArgumentException
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a reference to the method or call the method?

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: I want to pass the method having a string value , which is coming from different test class

Comment: `sel_prd` doesn't return anything. It needs to be `return self.driver....`

Comment: But why are you passing that to `self.driver.find_element()`? It's already returning the found element.

Comment: I  want to dynamically call the method based on the string coming from the test class. So the method will have that String value and it will click that element

Comment: Looks like selenium found a clickable element, which (when clicked) made a request to your server. However, the server considered the request malformed. This is evidenced by the fact we are in `check_response()` and that the detail includes a status code of `400`. You should try debugging your code to check a) what element it found, b) what endpoint it made a request to, and c) the parameters it sent to the endpoint. And then check to see if they are the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but to answer your question, here is a couple of examples using just normal functions and also methods of classes. Hope this help you in some way.

```
>>> def f1(f2_ref, msg: str):
...     f2_ref(msg)
...
>>> def f2(msg: str):
...     print(msg.upper())
...
>>> f1(f2, 'hello world')
HELLO WORLD
>>>
>>> class A:
...     def f1(self, f2_ref, msg: str):
...             f2_ref(msg)
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f1(f2, 'hello')
HELLO
>>> class B:
...     def echo_lower(self, msg: str):
...             print(msg.lower())
...
>>> b = B()
>>> a.f1(b.echo_lower, 'HELLO!')
hello!
```